# Is there an alternative to compile_error based on static analysis (e.g. by optimizer)

Tags: rust

I have a function called `foo`.

```rust
fn foo(val: bool) {
   if val {
      panic!("This should not ever happened");
   } else {
      // do something useful
   }
}

// somewhere else
foo(true); // this should cause compile error
```

What I want is stop compilation if the compiler will be sure, that function `foo` will be called with `true` value. I want to be informed as soon as possible (so compile time is better than runtime). So I want to something like `compile_error!` but based on static analysis. It is absolutely ok to compile it if the compiler is not sure if `true` branch will be called or not - program will panic at runtime.

`compile_error!` is sadly unusable for me because I don't want the following code failed on compile

```rust
if false {
   compile_error!("Some error");
}
```

Comment: Is there a more complex example that you could add? As it is, you could for instance avoid this by removing the argument entirely. In a more general case you could try to make the type system disallow what you want, but it is hard to say with just this example.

Comment: [`std::unreachable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) could help with optimizations, but I don't think there's any kind of static analysis available for this currently, at least not in the language without compiler plugins.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't have one. The problem is, that in the small projects I can somehow prevent it, in the bigger projects combination of changes from different developers could easily cause it.

Comment: IMO this is not an optimization problem but an invariant enforcement one. I.e., you don't want other to call your `foo` with value `true`. If that's what you want, try macro `std::debug_assert`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with `compile_error!`. The macro is evaluated way before things like code optimization are happening. There are basically only two contexts in which `compile_error!` is useful right now:

- Conditional compilation with `#[cfg(...)]`
- Macros generating code that may contain a `compile_error!`

Both of these are evaluated before the `compile_error!` error is emitted.

There is no nice functionality to let you do what you want to achieve. However, there exists a kind of *hack*. It is used by [the `no-panic` crate](https://github.com/dtolnay/no-panic) and causes an error at link time (something you usually see pretty rarely in Rust).

The trick works by inserting a reference to an unknown symbol at each panic location. If the optimizer (which runs very late in the compilation pipeline, but still mainly before linking) can remove the branch leading to the `panic`, it also removes the reference to the unknown symbol. If the optimizer cannot remove the branch, then the final code contains a reference to that unknown symbol and the linker will produce an "undefined reference to ..." error. It's not a nice error, but it stops the program from compiling.

Your goal is a bit more elaborate though: you only want an error if the compiler is sure that a panic will absolutely happen. That's more tricky, but you might be able to use this hack to solve it, too.